# CSS position fixed but other elements getting under it

Tags: css

I have set position of  my header as fixed 
But my next section is getting under it .
How to tweak this ? I have a work around by creating a div element and setting its height equal to the header . But what is the perfect semantic way to do this ? Is there any clear fix ?

Comment: can u show us the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a margin-top: to your next content section and set it to the height of your header.

If the header height changes across pages, you can keep it in sync with some JavaScript:

```
var headerHeight = document.getElementById("pageHeader").style.marginTop;
document.getElementById("topSection").style.marginTop = headerHeight;
```

Comment: What if height of the fixed header changes with different screen sizes , how should I give an appropriate margin-top  ? @Michael Dziedzic